# How to write Cleaner Nested Conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, react-native, coding-style

Using if statement we will get so much of nesting and if statement readability will reduce if the code size increases.

**If Statement** example:

```
if (item) {
 if (item === 'palladium') {
  printPalladiumPrice();
 } else if (item === 'silver') {
  printSilverPrice();
 } else if (item === 'gold') {
  printGoldPrice();
 } else if (item === 'platinum') {
  printPlatinumPrice();
 } else if (item === 'diamond') {
  printDiamonPrice();
 } else {
  printAllItemPrice();
 }
}
```

The same problem we will face with the Switch statement. If the size increases the Switch Case readability will reduce as shown below.

**Switch Case** example:

```
switch (item) {
 case 'palladium':
  printPalladiumPrice();
  break;

 case 'silver':
  printSilverPrice();
  break;

 case 'gold':
  printGoldPrice();
  break;

 case 'platinum':
  printPlatinumPrice();
  break;

 case 'diamond':
  printDiamondPrice();
  break;

 default:
  printAllItemPrice();
}
```

If we use JSON OBJECT our conditions will reduce to one single if statement and code will be much readable. Below is the example to write Cleaner Nested Conditions using the JSON Object.

**JSON Object** example:-

```
const itemObj = {
  'palladium': printPalladiumPrice,
  'silver': printSilverPrice,
  'gold': printGoldPrice,
  'platinum': printPlatinumPrice,
  'diamond': printDiamondPrice,
};

if (item in itemObj) {
  itemObj[item]();
}
```

Our conditions are now reduced to one single if and code is much readable.

Comment: is it a question or answer ?

Comment: how about `window[print${item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1)}Price]()` :D. Anyways, I suggest you ask this in the stack code review :)

Comment: Actually, I'd much rather have that switch case, it's safer.

Comment: you can create a `factory method` which uses the `object` or `switch case` both are good to go.

Comment: A crucial `if` statement is missing in the JSON object method. You aren't comparing the material name with the incoming item. At the moment, you are triggering all the methods one by one.